# Qt, QPlainTextEdit and non-printable characters

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I wonder if there is any possibility to render special characters (0-31 ASCII, for example) my own way in Qt/QPlainTextEdit? I want to render them as small rectangles as seen in this screenshot: [image: screenshot] ...or as Notepad++ is doing it. My goal is to be able see all characters. So if a character fails to render with current font (there is no such char for example), a small square should be rendered instead.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in a QT text edit that does this "out of the box" you could however subclass a QT object to get the basic functionality and implement this yourself.

Comment: @AJG85, thanks, but it is obvious. The question is _what_ I should subclass, or _how_.

Comment: have you searched or asked around on http://www.qtforum.org/index.html you may be able to find some examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Qt does have ways to represent non-characters in `QTextDocument` which is used in `QTextEdit` and `QPlainTextEditor`. There's a sample on inserting an SVG object into a text edit:
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/richtext-textobject.html

Or you can [use](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtextdocument.html#setDocumentLayout) your own [`QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html#drawInlineObject) to handle the drawing of various text objects in the `QTextDocument`.