# How to display Unicode values in the little boxes?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, fonts

In the pluma editor (on Linux) and sometimes in a web browser, for unrecognized characters, I see a little box with the Unicode value inside. I have seen 4 digit and 6 digit code boxes.

**I WANT** these little boxes with numbers (as appropriate.) How do I get these to display in a C++ Qt program?

Can you get a two digit box?

Here is an example, as shown in the pluma editor:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a different font?

Comment: @MrEricSir You misunderstand my question. I WANT the little boxes for codes that are not printable. It's not a font problem. In my program they either show as empty boxes or nothing at all (like a space).

Comment: Ah ha! Not sure if I should vote this one up because it's an interesting question or down because at the end of the day it's asking for a tool. Think I'll go for up, but I'd go digging through the qt docs.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the up vote :-)   Digging through any docs... What on earth would I be looking for "little boxes with numbers in them"? Really? It's the picture that tells a human what I want.

Comment: I'd start with a websearch for "qt non printable characters". [Qt, QPlainTextEdit and non-printable characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226253/qt-qplaintextedit-and-non-printable-characters) looks like it might get you started.

Comment: @user4581301 Again thank you. I will look there some more, but I was hoping to use some code that has already been written. Doing it from scratch looks like it would take me a long time to figure a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These glyphs are produced by the default fallback font for the system/platform – they are not inherently a feature of Qt.

If you want all characters to be rendered this way, you can use the [Unicode BMP Fallback font](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=UnicodeBMPFallbackFont), which has glyphs for all code points in the basic multilingual plane as hex digits in a box.

Comment: Thank you very much. This will work. The "look" of the numbers in these boxes are slightly different than those in my original picture, but the idea is the same. Pluma and the browsers must be using something different yet that does not require a font like this one. I would be interested in how they do it too.